# Liveness Detection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, face-recognition, google-mlkit

I have an app for attendance that is based on a facial recognition system. I want to implement liveness detection or antispoofing. I found some models and solutions but none of these solutions work in offline mode (no internet mode). My app works in offline mode without internet.

I made my app in the Flutter framework and I am using ML Kit. If anyone has any idea how to do it or has any solution or code regarding this issue. It will be very helpful to me.

Comment: ML Kit does not support face recognition. It only supports face detection. It doesn't support liveness detection either.

Comment: @DongChen so is there any other option for this that will work in offline mode.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on this. You can wait for others to comment on this or search for possible options online.

Comment: @HassanGujjar Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: @Lefty still no

Comment: @HassanGujjar Hi hassan did you get solution of liveness detection.?

Comment: @SabahatHussainQureshi no

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **tflite** dependency to achieve live face recognition in flutter.
you can use below link to refer more about tflite. which is using to recognize live camera faces.

https://pub.dev/packages/tflite

And for offline mode you have to implement PWA(progressive web app) to your flutter app. use below document to implement pwa to your flutter app.
**Note : pwa only works with https**. so you can make build your flutter app using firebase to make your app secured

https://medium.flutterdevs.com/progressive-web-app-flutter-62c7dea05fc5